# Using 2D projections in cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

The default projections in cocos2d ios are 3D projections.
However, this can be changed to 2D projections.

What are the **advantages/disadvantages** of using 2D projections in cocos2d?

What are the possible **side effects** of switching from the default 3D projections to 2D?

Comment: the default is 2d projection in cocos 2.x

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030664/what-are-good-reasons-to-enable-2d-projection-with-cocos2d-iphone